# No audio/images when deploying jar on another host

Tags: java, image, audio, jar

The following Java code (stored in a Jar file) works on my computer, but when I deploy it to another computer I only see the text, but not the audio or images.

Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;


public class SlotMachines
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        UIManager.put("OptionPane.background",new ColorUIResource(250,175,0));
        UIManager.put("Panel.background",new ColorUIResource(0,0,0));
        String ask;
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Input your cash?");
        lbl.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lbl.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        ask = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, lbl);
            double money = Double.parseDouble(ask);
        int again;
        int rerun = 1;
        Random generate = new Random();
        while (rerun == 1) //rerun while loop
        {
            JLabel pnl = new JLabel("Would you like to play Slots?");
            pnl.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16));
            pnl.setForeground(Color.WHITE);    
            again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, pnl);

            int bet = 2;

            if (again == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            {
            JLabel lab = new JLabel("Your cash stays at: " + money);
            lab.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16));
            lab.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, lab);
            }

            while (again == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                File Winner = new File("jackpot.au");
                File Mega = new File("mega.au");
                File lose = new File("lose.au");
                if (money >= 2)
                {
                    money -= bet;
                    int[] arr = new int[3];
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                    {
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("slotmachine.jpg");
                        arr[i] = generate.nextInt(10);              
                        JLabel label = new JLabel("[" + arr[i] + "] ");
                        label.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.BOLD, 125));
                        label.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, label, " ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);

                    }
                    if (arr[0] == arr[1] && arr[1] == arr[2])
                    {

                        JLabel win = new JLabel("JACKPOT!!! BET X 5!");
                        win.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                        PlaySound(Mega);
                        win.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 140));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, win);
                        money += bet*5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (arr[0] == arr[1] || arr[0] == arr[2] || arr[1] == arr[2])
                    {
                            JLabel small = new JLabel("Rolling In cash! Doubles!");
                            small.setForeground(Color.magenta);
                            PlaySound(Winner);
                            small.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, small);
                            money += bet*2;
                    }
                    }

                    JLabel cash = new JLabel("Your cash: $" + (int)money);
                    cash.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    cash.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 18));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, cash);

                    if (money >= 2)
                    {
                        JLabel big = new JLabel("Would you like to spin again?");
                        big.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                        big.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16));
                        again = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, big);

                        if (again != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    {
                            JLabel hell = new JLabel("You came out of hell with: $" + (int)money);
                            hell.setForeground(Color.RED);
                            hell.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 18));
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, hell);
                            rerun = 0;
                    }
                    }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JLabel sorry = new JLabel("Sorry you can't afford to spin, your card is at: $" + money);
                        sorry.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                        sorry.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 16));
                        PlaySound(lose);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, sorry);
                        again = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
                    }

            }
            rerun = 0;
        }
    }
    static void PlaySound(File Sound)
    {
        try{
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Sound));
            clip.start();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the image and audio files are on your local machine already, in locations the class file finds by default, so it works? Are you sure you're not only including in the jar file the audio and image files in the jar file, but also that when the jar file is unpacked with `jar -xf`, the files are extracted into a path relative to your class file, such that the class file can find them? I guess because you haven't created absolute or relative paths to these resources in your code, the code expects them to be in the same package location (same directory) as the class file itself.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two probable causes:

1. You forgot to take your assests with  you to another computer.
2. You packaged assests into the jars, but you should be using `ClassLoader.getResource()` to retrieve them because they are on the classpath not in the working directory. Something like this:

   ```
   public static void playSound(String pathToMusicOnClasspath) {
       try {
           Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
           clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(pathToMusicOnClasspath)));
           clip.start();
       } catch(Exception ignore) {}
   }
   ```

   call it like this:

   ```
   playSound("jackpot.au");
   ```

   This should be done to your `ImageIcon`, too.

   ```
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("slotmachine.jpg"));
   ```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific. I am new(ish) to java and I dont know exactly where to add this or how to do it.

Comment: The method getSystemResource(String) in the type ClassLoader is not applicable for the arguments (File)